# database.php de Laravel no permite modificaciones

Tags: php, laravel-7

Tengo un problema raro, al menos para mí.
Por alguna razón, laravel bloquea (si vale el término) el archivo database.php dentro de la carpeta config.
El síntoma es el siguiente:
Cualquier modificación que se realice en este archivo, (crear conexión nueva, modificar conexión existente,etc) el framework no lo ve, es decir... sigue funcionando como si no se hubiera tocado el archivo. Es más, hasta llegue a borrar todo el contenido del mismo (con el fin que se rompa), guardando los cambios y todo sigue funcionando con normalidad.
¿Alguien sabe si se trata de algún bloqueo de seguridad de laravel en algún lugar?

Versión de Laravel 7.0

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: en laravel se pueden usar en otros procesos las coneciones a la base de datos, 1 estas en la misma carpeta, 2 la conecion a la base esta en database.php, no tienes algun plugin instalado, 3 seguro que estas en la misma carpera...

Comment: Debe estar cacheada la configuración https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#configuration-caching. Corre `php artisan config:clear` e intenta otra vez